# error: no such device: GUID

Tags: 10.04, server, installation, raid, grub2

I have an old(er) machine that I'm trying to wipe out and install ubuntu 10.04.  The machine has 4 500GB HDDs that were previously set up as a raid.  When I run the installer, it asks if I want to "Activate Serial ATA RAID devices" to which I usually answer 'Yes'.  However, once the install is complete, I always get the following prompt:

> error: no such device: GUID
>
> grub rescue>

Most of the posts I've been able to find through google deal more with running multiple OSes and less with raid (which may or may not be the actual problem).

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to recover the grub installation? 
I could recover grub many times by following these instructions at: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Grub2#Recover

First of all, you must start your system from a live cd. Then

"**METHOD 3 - CHROOT**

This method of installation uses the chroot command to gain access to the broken system's files. Once the chroot command is issued, the LiveCD treats the broken system's / as its own. Commands run in a chroot environment will affect the broken systems filesystems and not those of the LiveCD.

1) Boot to the LiveCD Desktop (Ubuntu 9.10 or later). Please note that the Live CD must be the same as the system you are fixing - either 32-bit or 64-bit (if not then the chroot will fail).

2) Open a terminal - Applications, Accessories, Terminal.
3) Determine your normal system partition - (the switch is a lowercase "L")

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

If you aren't sure, run

```
df -Th
```

Look for the correct disk size and ext3 or ext4 format.

4) Mount your normal system partition:

Substitute the correct partition: sda1, sdb5, etc.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt
```

# Example: sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

5) Only if you have a separate boot partition:
sdYY is the /boot partition designation (for example sdb3)

```
sudo mount /dev/sdYY /mnt/boot
```

6)
Mount the critical virtual filesystems:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev  /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts  /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys
```

7)
Chroot into your normal system device:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

8) If there is no /boot/grub/grub.cfg or it's not correct, create one using

```
update-grub
```

9)
Reinstall GRUB 2:

Substitute the correct device - sda, sdb, etc. Do not specify a partition number.

```
grub-install /dev/sdX
```

10) Verify the install (use the correct device, for example sda. Do not specify a partition):

```
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
```

11)
Exit chroot: CTRL-D on keyboard
12)
Unmount virtual filesystems:

```
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sys
```

13)
If you mounted a separate /boot partition:

```
sudo umount /mnt/boot
```

14)
Unmount the LiveCD's /usr directory:

```
sudo umount /mnt/usr
```

15)
Unmount last device:

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

16)
Reboot.

```
sudo reboot
```

"